# android studio 3.1 always getting error about unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating android studio to 3.1, suddenly it will gives error if I add a new dependency for example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.4'
}
```

it gives this error :

> Failed to resolve: com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.4

Also all my themes in my style gives red error and said Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme' but if I run my app it works very interesting issue.

Comment: `compile 'com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.3'`

Comment: it works looks normal

Comment: replace with compile 'com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.+'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Failed to resolve: com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.4

Make sure you added below in your ***Project Level*** **`build.gradle`** section.

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
      .........
        maven {
            url  "http://dl.bintray.com/florent37/maven"
        }
    }
```

**FYI**

If same problem coming, You can use OLD version

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Same, but version 1.0.3 worked for me.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.florent37:android-slidr:1.0.3'
}
```

try this